# How to install tweepy via pip?

Tags: python, pip, tweepy

I write down

```
pip install tweepy
```

but I got an Error such as

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
C:\>pip install tweepy
 ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Before I wrote this code, I install pip, but why can't I install tweepy????

Comment: If my answer solved your question can you mark it as solved by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your terminal enter: `python -m pip install tweepy`.